# Java Split on string not working

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following crash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1010, result=-1, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.forsale.forsale/com.forsale.forsale.view.ItemsActivity}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1
},
^
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1
},
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1340)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1324)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:946)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2325)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2367)
at com.forsale.forsale.view.ItemsActivity.preserveAttributes(ItemsActivity.java:1449)
at com.forsale.forsale.view.ItemsActivity.onActivityResult(ItemsActivity.java:1148)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
```

my code is as following :

```
String[] items = attributes.split("},");
```

Comment: Err, consider reading the javadoc for the APIs you intend to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` function take as argument a regex pattern (as it is written in the errors)

`}`is a special character for regex

try to escape it like that

```
   String[] items = attributes.split("\\},");
```

Comment: Did not need to escape it trying this on eclipse : `String a = "hell},o";
        String[] items = a.split("},");
        System.out.println(items[0]);` output was "hell"

Comment: Yes indeed but it is perhaps due to Java version (in the error logs of the OP we see that he use Java to make android app which may have an impact of the choice of JDK)